# Summarize data with loop action

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of fruit in A1:A20, & then the user of my excel file will give the check mark ("V") in B1:B20 if they want to choose one of fruit in the list of column A.

The problem is I want automatically to summarise in sheet2 a list of fruit which the user give the check mark in column B. Do you guys any idea how to solve it?

Comment: what version o Excel are you using?? If **Excel365** you can use `FILTER()` and no VBA is needed.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365, Excel for iPad, etc., you have access to the `FILTER` function:

- [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)

You set the data range you want to use as a result set, and then set the criteria to filter by, in your case `Sheet1!A1:A20` and `Sheet1!B1:B20="v"` respectively.

Place this in `A1` on `Sheet2`, and the list is created and then automatically updated.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A1:A20,Sheet1!B1:B20="v")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a PivotTable

[image]

..........

Answer (score 0):

This uses a "helper column".  In `Sheet1` cell **C1** enter:

```
=IF(B1<>"",1,0)
```

In `Sheet1` cell **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="","",1+MAX(C1:$C$1))
```

and copy downwards.  A typical example:

[image]

Note that column **C** marks the selected fruits with a simple sequential inter sequence.

Finally in `Sheet2 cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>MAX(Sheet1!C$1:C$20),"",INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$20,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C$1:C$20),0))
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

If you need VBA for another reason then:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, rng As Range, r As Range
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = s1.Range("B1:B20")
    
    i = 1
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            s2.Cells(i, 1).Value = r.Offset(0, -1).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could place this in Sheet1 code pane (rightclik on Sheet1 tab and select "View Code")

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    With Sheet2
        .Range("A1:A20").ClearContents
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In Range("A1:A20")
            If cel.Offset(, 1) = "v" Then .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = cel.Value2
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

this way, everytime the user operates on Sheet1 B1:B20 cells, the Sheet2 list is automaticaly updated